# Connect to MySQL via Websockets

Tags: mysql, websocket

Has anyone tried to connect to a MySQL server via websockets? How did you set up the server side?

I came across http://blog.alex.org.uk/2012/02/16/using-apache-websocket-to-proxy-tcp-connection/ and I thought I could use it to map a websocket to the MySQL TCP port.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) as a bridge to enable a browser connection to any type of raw TCP service. Disclaimer: I wrote websockify.